# CORS error with MSAL, Angular and ASP.NET Core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm trying to build an ASP.NET Core webapi + Angular website where users can login using Microsoft personal or work or school email. I followed the instructions described here:
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/README.md

But encouter this issue,

1. The angular website load, and the protected component on the home page trigger the login procedure
2. The microsoft web site appear
3. I login
4. The browser load the following url: https://localhost:44321/#id_token=...&state=...
5. The website reload again (for a second time after the signin)
6. And I see the following error

   Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=...' (redirected from 'https://localhost:44321/Environment/GetUserInfo') from origin 'https://localhost:44321' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

when debugging locally with Visual Studio 2019 16.4.2 and chrome 79.0.3945.88

Any idea?
**Thanks**

I've created my project using

```
dotnet new angular -o myapp
```

And created an app registration in Azure.Portal
Authentication with following redirect URI

- https://localhost:44321/signin-microsoft
- https://login.microsoftonline.com/
- http://localhost:30662/
- https://localhost:44321/signin-oidc
- https://localhost:44321/

Checked all the "Suggested Redirect URIs for public clients"
Logout URL: https://localhost:44321/signout-callback-oidc
Implicit grant: Access tokens and ID tokens
Live SDK support: Yes
Default client type: No

Certificate & Secret
I've created a client secret, becaused I tried to use Microsoft provider (see commented code below) then tried with AzureAd

API Permission
Microsoft.Graph User.Read

Expose an API
Scope = [Application ID URI]/access_as_user, Admins Only
Client application = [CLIENT_ID_FROM_AZURE_PORTAL], scope above

**Server side**
**appsettings.json**

```
 "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "[Application ID URI]",
    "ClientId": "[CLIENT_ID_FROM_AZURE_PORTAL]",
    "TenantId": "common",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddCors(options =>
  {
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
        builder =>
        {
          builder
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyOrigin();
        });
  });

  services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
  {
    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
  });

  // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
  services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
  {
    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
  });

  //services
  //  .AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  //  .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  //  .AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
  //{
  //  microsoftOptions.ClientId = "[CLIENT_ID_FROM_AZURE_PORTAL]";
  //  microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = "[CLIENT_SECRET_FROM_AZURE_PORTAL]";
  //});

  services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

  services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
  {
    options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
  });

  services.AddControllers(options =>
  {
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
  })
  .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");

  if (env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  }
  else
  {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
  }

  app.UseHttpsRedirection();
  app.UseCookiePolicy();
  app.UseStaticFiles();
  if (!env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
  }

  app.UseRouting();

  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseAuthorization();

  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
    endpoints.MapControllers();
  });

  app.UseSpa(spa =>
  {
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
      spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
  });
}
```

**Client side**
**app.module.ts**

```
...
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MsalModule, MsalGuard, MsalInterceptor } from '@azure/msal-angular';
...
export const protectedResourceMap: [string, string[]][] = [
  ['https://localhost:44321/Environment/GetUserInfo', ['[Application ID URI]/access_as_user']],
  ['https://localhost:44321/api/Environment/GetUserInfo', ['[Application ID URI]/access_as_user']],
  ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']],
  ['https://login.microsoftonline.com/common', ['user.read']]
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    CounterComponent,
    EntitySignoffComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([]),
    MsalModule.forRoot({
      clientID: [CLIENT_ID_FROM_AZURE_PORTAL],
      authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
      redirectUri: "https://localhost:44321/",
      validateAuthority: true,
      cacheLocation: "localStorage",
      storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // dynamically set to true when IE11
      postLogoutRedirectUri: "https://localhost:44321/",
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
      popUp: false,
      unprotectedResources: [ "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common" ],
      protectedResourceMap: protectedResourceMap
    }
    ),
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [MsalGuard] }
      { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent, canActivate: [MsalGuard] },
    ])
  ],
  providers: [NavMenuComponent, { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MsalInterceptor, multi: true }],
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run myapp:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-server": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.14",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^0.1.4",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.2.6",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.1",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.10.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "zone.js": "0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.21",
    "@angular/cli": "8.3.21",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~13.1.2",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.1",
    "typescript": "3.5.3"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.5.4",
    "tslint": "~5.20.1"
  }
}
```

[Error in Chrome after login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WA8zu.png)

Comment: Please check if the issue is caused by [same one discussed in this github issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1117#issuecomment-555399310).

Comment: I've updated to those line
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
.AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
But now I get a 401, and it still load the webpage twice after login
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "OK", url: "https://localhost:44321/Environment/GetUserInfo", ok: false, …}

Comment: Hi, has your issue been solved now ?

Comment: Hi Stanley, no I have the same issue, check the image above "Error in Chrome after login"

Answer (score 3):

Per my understanding, these two official samples will meet your requirement perfectly.

I have modified the official demo and integrated it for you. Pls follow the steps below to make them work :

1. For API side .[You can download my code here](https://stanstroage.blob.core.windows.net/container2/3.-Web-api-call-Microsoft-graph-for-personal-accounts.zip).

1)Got to Azure portal and register an Azure AD app for it :
[image]

2)Note its application id and created an client secret for it. Type them into `appsettings.json` :
[image]

3) Back to Azure portal, expose an API so that client-side could request permission of it :
[image]

4) API side's work is done , you can run this project directly.

2. For angular side, you can [get my code here](https://stanstroage.blob.core.windows.net/container2/MsalAngularjsDemoApp.zip) .

1) Register an Azure AD app for this client-side :
[image]

2) Add a permission to this app so that it could access your backend : 
[image]
[image]
Click grant permission button to finish the process : 
[image]
These two demo all are based on Azure AD V2.0 endpoint which allows personal accounts and school work accounts to log in and do some actions.

3) Do some config on Auth blade so that it could get tokens needed as a public client :
[image]

4) All steps are done for angular side , `npm start` to run it , access it on : `http://localhost:44302/`
I have tested on my local and it works perfectly for me:
[image]

If you dont know how to combine these two app, pls let me know .

Comment: I tried to combine those application, but got the following error on the client side: Error :login_required; Error description:AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in. The cookies used to represent the user's session were not sent in the request to Azure AD. This can happen if the user is using Internet Explorer or Edge, and the web app sending the silent sign-in request is in different IE security zone than the Azure AD endpoint. I'm using chrome, If possible could you upload your version so I can exclude the merging as a potential issue

Comment: Hi @D2O , I have updated my answer  with detailed steps , pls have a check

Comment: Hi Stanley, sorry for the delay, I followed your steps but had to do some extra tasks; for the server I had to clone Microsoft.Identity.Web project from github and reference it; on the client side I had to update app.js with the clientID and webApiScores. Now the website login and logout, however when I call the api I still have this error: Getting error in the response: {"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"https://localhost:44351/api/todolist","data":"AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in

Comment: But one thing I've learned from your steps is that the server and the client have seperate registration, that I didn't know, I though it was one registration for both. Are my changes all right. Is it possible I've missed something else. Thanks for helping

Comment: I added a link with a snapshot from my browser with the error and the logout button

Comment: I wish I found this months ago

Comment: Links are all dead. If this solution ever worked it's useless now.

Answer (score 2):

Not too many upvotes for this question, but I also got a CORS error when working with MSAL. For me it was caused by a mismatch between the authentication scheme selected for @azure/msal-angular and the authentication scheme expected by the back-end.

In my case, both needed to be JWTBearer or 'Bearer {token}'.

The reason you get a CORS is that the mismatch triggers the back end to try and authenticate with microsoft, causing a redirect (and cross-origin request). By aligning the front-end and back-end authentication schemes, the problem went away.